# Information on the moderator candidates

Tags: discussion, election

*This question has been posted on the meta of all the other sites undergoing elections, so just in case you've missed it I'm adding it here. Copied mainly from [ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf), who has no account here.*

[Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150097/yi-jiang) has put together a nice site that use the Stack Overflow API to display information on the moderator candidates.

[Click here to see all the information](http://se.awio.com/election.html).

The information presented is:

What the candidate wrote when nominating themselves.

- Answers/Questions on the main site and its meta
- Up-vote/down-vote ratio
- Average reputation earned per post
- Average reputation earned per day.
- Participation in other Stack Exchange sites.

It displays what Yi Jiang considers to be noteworthy badges and whether the nominee has the badge and a summary of their recent activity.

The information is presented as is with no commentary.

It came about from this question on MSO: [Moderator nomination possibly useful statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75454/59303).

Comment: Closing this so it doesn't clog up the Unanswered tab.